# Generating infinite array of pulses (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, plot, fft, matlab-figure

> I am trying to generate an infinite array of pulses (in this case hyperbolic secant pulses) in Matlab as in [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARook.jpg).

**Attempt:**

So, I want to plot the actual pulse train in time domain, as well as its spectrum in Fourier domain (using `fft`).  when I define the temporal and frequency axes:

```
t = [-tspan : dt : tspan];
w = [-1/dt : 1/tspan : 1/dt]
```

If I substitute `inf` for the span of the time grid I will exceed the maximum number of variables and get errors. So, how can I generate this infinite array
of pulses for a given function (say `u(t)=sech(t/a)`)?

Comment: I don't understand why you need an infinite array of pulses.  Obviously MATLAB can't store an infinite number of pulses for you because of memory constraints.

Comment: Yes, that is true. But is there a way to simulate this situation? Because the plot in my post was generated in Matlab, the text says it shows an infinite array of pulses (only 7 shown). Then in the frequency domain the spectrum of this infinite train of pulses will consist of sharp spikes (Dirac delta-functions), this is exactly what is theoretically expected.

Comment: If you want to plot them, then you can plot them independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't explicitly represent an infinite set of pulses by storing the amplitude at each time point, because that would require infinite memory. Instead, you can define a function `f(t)` that returns the amplitude of your pulse train at time point `t`. You can think of `f` as implicitly defining an infinite pulse train. To plot it, just choose your time limits and evaluate `f(t)` at some points within those bounds.

For the spectrum, you have a couple options. One is to derive it analytically. In this case, you would define a function `F(w)`, which returns the value of the spectrum at frequency 'w'. You can similarly think of this as infinite and plot it in the same way.

The other option is to compute the spectrum numerically. In this case, you'd generate samples of `f(t)`. Make sure your sampling rate is above the Nyquist frequency. Then, use some function to calculate the spectrum of the sampled signal. In general, this is an approximation because your sampled signal can only have finite length. As the length grows shorter, the approximation becomes less accurate. Also, there can be artifacts in the spectrum that represent discontinuities at the beginning/end of the sampled signal, but don't reflect the 'true' signal. There are two general ways to mitigate these issues: 1) Use a long sampled signal (but obviously it can't be infinitely long). 2) Use a window function, which reduces edge effects. For periodic signals like yours, the sampled region should span an integer number of periods.

Comment: That is right. Also I was told that if the time axis is an integer multiple of the spacing in time between the two successive pulses (i.e. repetition rate `T`), then the periodic boundary conditions of the DFT will ensure the pulse train is truly infinite even if you have a finite number of pulses. So I defined my `t=[-N*T : dt  : N*T]`, but I am not getting the sharp Dirac spikes like in the picture. And when I use a span which is NOT a multiple of T, I again get the same plot shape. Why is that?

Comment: @Merin What does it look like instead?

Comment: In [this picture](http://i.imgur.com/hh5qYYt.jpg) the first set is for 1 pulse, second one is for a pulse pair, last one is for infinite array. When I make my plot, the spectrum looks something like the second set. I don't get the sharp Dirac spikes like the last image.

Comment: @Merin Try two things. 1) Many pulses (e.g. several hundred). 2) A single pulse pair, but choose the time points carefully. Set it up so that, if you were to concatenate many copies of the short signal, it would be a valid pulse train.